# What is the right way to preprocess images in Keras while fine-tuning pre-trained models

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

What is the right way to preprocess the data in Keras while fine-tuning the pre-trained models in keras.applications for our own data?

Keras provides the following `preprocess_input` functions

[keras.applications.imagenet_utils.preprocess_input](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L149)

[keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/inception_v3.py#L398)

[keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/xception.py#L272)

[keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2.preprocess_input](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/inception_resnet_v2.py#L46)

Looking inside it seems like for inception_v3, xception, and inception_resnet_v2, it calls [keras.applications.imagenet_utils.preprocess_input](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L149) with `mode='tf'`. While for other models it sets `mode='caffe'` each of which perform a different transformation.

In the blog post about transfer learning from Francois chollet -- https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html -- it is normalized to `[0, 1]` through a division with 255. Shouldn't the preprocess_input functions in Keras be used instead?

Also it is not clear whether the input images should be in RGB or BGR? Is there any consistency regarding this or is it specific to the pre-trained model being used?

Comment: What pre-trained model are you using?

Comment: Hello Daneile, I am not fixed upon one particular pre-trained models. I want to fine-tune all of them on my data and find out which one performs best.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Always use the `preprocess_input` function in the corresponding model-level module. That is, use `keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input` for `InceptionV3` and `keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input` for `ResNet50`.

The `mode` argument specifies the preprocessing method used when training the original model. `mode='tf'` means that the pre-trained weights are converted from TF, where the authors trained model with `[-1, 1]` input range. So are `mode='caffe'` and `mode='torch'`.

The input to `applications.*.preprocess_input` is always RGB. If a model expects BGR input, the channels will be permuted inside `preprocess_input`.

The blog post you've mentioned was posted before the `keras.applications` module was introduced. I wouldn't recommend using it as a reference for transfer learning with `keras.applications`. Maybe it'll be better to try the examples in the [docs](https://keras.io/applications/) instead.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! In case the mean and standard-deviation of our data is different from image-net, then what is the best way to account for it? Wouldn't the transformation to the target range using the statistics derived from image-net data (as opposed to our data) end up being bad?

Comment: It's possible. Although in my own experience it doesn't matter much, I think it would depend on the dataset.

Comment: @Yu-Yang Does Keras provide references to where the weights and model are obtained from as well as how the inputs were preprocessed?  It would be nice for a user to be able to verify that the inputs were preprocessed in a certain way for the training of a model.  Currently if I use Keras' vgg19 model, then I need to just trust that the way Keras is preprocessing the inputs is correct.

Comment: @user3731622 I think there's only partial information about this. You can find some links in the "License" section on the [doc](https://keras.io/applications/#inceptionresnetv2). Also you can probably find it in the code. Take [Inception-ResNet v2](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/inception_resnet_v2.py) as an example, since the weights are obtained from TF-slim, you can check if the preprocessing function in TF-slim matches the one in Keras.

Comment: You can also try to verify model performance (accuracy, etc.) on ImageNet. If the performance of the pretrained model matches the performance claimed by the authors, then the preprocessing is likely right.

Comment: Wish there was a simple reference someplace with a listing of what each of the preprocessing functions does.  They seem top secret.  Following links above does not reach the source code.  How can I find the actual source code (for the Keras pre-processing functions)?

Comment: It's placed under the `keras-applications` repo now: [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/1.0.8/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py#L157).

Comment: Thanks for an excellent explanation. If you include an example it would be even better. Or link to an example in the docs e.g.: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/xception/preprocess_input

Comment: One question is why is keras pretrained weights from imagenet for resnet50 using BGR channel order? Where did this come from? Was it something due to imagenet, or something due to "caffe"? And why don't we have new weights that are TF specific and doesn't require changing the channel order.